# C# Console application % math always return 0

Tags: c#

Hello guys i have a small problem at my console application
i have a text file got 
19862 line

```
String[] lines= File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\ThElitEyeS\\Desktop\\PHP\\name\\names.txt");
int c = lines.Length;
int i = 1;
foreach (String line in lines) {
    long f = ((i++ / c) * 100);
    Console.WriteLine(f + "%");
}
```

the value always return 0%
except the last one its return 100%
and that is my problem i hope to find question fast :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a integer devision and that will be rounded.

Example:

```
i = 1 and c= 100
result is 0.01  -> rounded to 0
0 * 100 = 0
```

Instead try

```
long f = ((i++ / (double) c) * 100);
```

to force a floating point devision.

Comment: @ThElitEyeS But why is `f` declared as a `long`?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a working answer, but I would not use `double` here, when integer division (which doesn't round, but truncates) is sufficient:

```
long f = i++ * 100 / c;
```

Comment: Is it possible some compilers would 'optimize' this to still be i++ / c * 100, with the same original error?

Comment: @3Pi (I thought you meant something else initially) Such a compiler would be broken. The evaluation is well-defined, and compiling it to something else that gives different results is invalid.